How to do Bendak's Bounty Quest in KotOR 1?
I've tried several HUNDRED times to kill him:
I run to the side and try and attack and I've tried the running back and forth tactic thing: DOESN'T WORK!
I'm on NSwitch.
Any Specific stuff to use and strategies?

Well it requires a lot of prep work.
My advice is to do this as the LAST thing outside of the main quest to leave the planet. Stock up on all the grenades you find along the way and just keep throwing them. Early game grenades are the best source of high burst damage.
This is how i did it.

well im doing the sith base by the way can i still do it after the sith base or does Canderous just interupt once you try to go to the deuling and take you to Davik?

@PianoCat98 in all honesy i haven't played in about 15 years, so a little bit fuzzy on the details xD
I just remember grenading the last boss in the dueling area to death because i kept losing in all mymore conventional attempts.
